# Unable to use for each loop in C# for strings

Tags: c#

```
int num = 12;
string typecasted = Convert.ToString(num);
foreach(string i in typecasted){
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

I was trying to use for each loop function for int but it does not use int that's why I try to type caste and then I could use but the output was `Cannot convert type 'char' to string'`

Comment: A `string` is made up of one of more `char` elements. If you want to loop through a string, you need to loop through the _characters_ of that string. More importantly, though, is that you should figure out which programming language you're using before you post! Even if the above code was valid C#, it still wouldn't compile in Java or C++.

Comment: A `string` is not a list of `strings`, not sure why you would expect that. Also: nobody is going to help you if you don't take the time to format your question appropriately

Comment: What would you expect your code to do? Print the digits? A `string` is composed of `char`s (as the error suggests).

Comment: Okay I have just started that's why I don't know much about this language, don't be rude for your gestures

Answer (score 1):

A string is composed of characters, not strings. Your loop should be

```
foreach(char i in typecasted){
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

or if you prefer implicity typing

```
foreach(var i in typecasted){
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```